# Pass id of control to generalized jquery function to get value not worked

Tags: jquery

When I pass id of control to generalized function that returns value it not works n give compilation error.

```
getval('txtid');

function getval(id)
{
 var value =  $('#<%= '+ id +'.ClientID %>').val();//Error
 }
```

it give an compilation error Expression Expected.

Comment: Is this a typo: `function getval('txtid');` ???

Comment: Are you actually trying to concatenate a javascript variable into your serverside code, hoping the server has access to code running on the clients computer, or are you somehow using an other templating system where this would actually work ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getval('txtid'); //invalid
```

When calling a function no need to prefix with `function` keyword.

```
getval('txtid');  //valid
```

---

another maybe

```
                             |-----------missing space
var value =  $('#<%= '+ id +' .ClientID %>').val();
               //leave a space when you add class
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is either:

```
getval('txtid');


function getval(id)
{
 var value =  $("input[id$='" + id +"']").val().....
}
```

or you could add a class or custom attribute to the `controls` that you can select on

[more info available](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

First off all You have called the function wrongly:

Change:

```
function getval('txtid');
```

To:

```
getval('txtid');
```

And also You need to return Sometimes from the function which you have called(not compulsory but in your function call will not yield nothing):

```
function getval(id)
{
    var value =  $("#<%= '+ id +'.ClientID %>").val();// or u can use $("[id$='"+id+"']").val()
   return value;// wiil retun you txtid i think u want this
 }
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3M99/)**

Comment: Is your control server side rutat="server"

Comment: yes ....it works if id name is staic..function getval()
{
    var value =  $('#<%= txtid.ClientID %>').val();
   return value;
 }..but i want to one function used for all....

Comment: var value =  $("#<%= '+ id +'.ClientID %>").val(); add double quotes

Comment: Or u can try this $("[id$='"+id+"']").val()